# error ejecucion IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web, iis

Buenas Dias.
quisiera que me ayuden estoy subiendo mi pagina web en un **IIS** mi web config es este codigo:

```
<system.web>

  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />

  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

</system.web>
```

```
<add name="CnxUsu" connectionString="wZhyFoK5oBXaBFXNVySITwTMhFY7C3j/x6DJIUs0jQRLy585tK7zEDBzFT+2hDlPDMf0iRvNU3cHbt8ZmcBxZVL19Rc5+nKXUvX1Fzn6cpeqxEkfr3XPilRKZCu1Ctg1B/2i0Q5wWaI133mgd9HkWQ==">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que muestras es un error bastante genérico, una de las principales causas es que al archivo web.config le haga falta cerrar una etiqueta o tenga caracteres de más que impiden que se forme adecuadamente la estructura xml, sugiero que revises inicialmente esto que acabo de comentar.

Comment: ya lo solucione @Flxtr muchas gracias por comentar el problema era en mi codigo fuente por favor me podrias ayudar en otra pregunta que hice de excel con IIS

Comment: Si has solucionado el problema te sugiero que publiques la respuesta para ir consolidando una base de conocimientos más robusta, y la podrás marcar como respuesta aceptada en 48 hrs (ahora reviso la otra pregunta :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el web.config(*no confundir con el web.config que esta dentro de la carpeta View*s), debajo de `configuration>system.web` agrega la siguiente etiqueta:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Esto lo que hara sera mostrarte con claridad el error. Si te preguntas porque hay que configurar esto, es por seguridad. No es bueno que el stacktrace todo el mundo lo este viendo ya que en los ojos equivocados puede hacerte muchos daño.

Te aconsejo que le cambies el valor a `On` cuando termines. Si prefieres no cambiar la configuracion, entonces prueba la aplicacion en tu IIS local ya que localmente siempre estara `Off`.

[En la pagina oficial da mas informacion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx).